# How to get unique date from multiple dates based on condition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

[image]

How do I get unique dates from the table "timelog" for the dates where isParent is not 1.

In the table, 2022-01-10 should not come as the result as this date has isParent as 1.

So far, I have written query like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT session::date 
FROM timelog
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM timelog WHERE isParent = 0)
```

Obviously, this is not working as intended. What changes do I need to make in this query to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function in `HAVING`, let your condition which didn't any `isParent = 1` date on `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT session::date
FROM timelog 
GROUP BY session::date
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN isParent = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=417ed8db99ffe247cbcf1f4ec7049705)

```
SELECT session::date
FROM timelog 
GROUP BY session::date
HAVING COUNT(*) filter(where isParent = 1) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT DISTINCT session::date FROM timelog WHERE isParent = 0
```

should work. All you are looking for is unique dates where the parent is 0 Correct? No aggregation needs to be applied ?

Comment: Looking for a unique date where isParent = 0 for the entire day

Comment: You could try grouping by date where parent is 0 in your sub query and aggregate it at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT session::date
FROM timelog
GROUP BY session::date
HAVING NOT ARRAY_AGG(isParent) && ARRAY[1]; -- NOT in array containing 1
```

Comment: This also works. I was trying what if I need to further filter by another column like profiled = 51 ?

Comment: @user2869736: That depends on what you're looking for, just records where profiled = 51 or a group where at least one of the records equals 51. That means you have have to put in a WHERE condition or in a HAVING condition. WHERE works on record level, HAVING works on group level.